# Python OpenCV cvCreateStructuringElementEx from Image, with shape = CV_SHAPE_CUSTOM

Tags: python, opencv

Anyone know how to create a `cvCreateStructuringElementEx` using a image?
I'm trying use `opencv.cv.cvCreateStructuringElementEx()`,
my struture is a bmp 160x120, black, with a half ellipse in white.

```
im = Image.open("struture.jpeg", "r")
im = im.convert("1")
val = numpy.uint(im.getdata())
gim = opencv.cv.cvCreateStructuringElementEx(im.size[0], im.size[1], im.size[0]/2, im.size[1]/2, opencv.cv.CV_SHAPE_CUSTOM, val)
```

So return the error:

```
TypeError: in method 'cvCreateStructuringElementEx', argument 6 of type 'int *'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might solved your problems:

```
int val[9]={0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the same instructions with Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.3.0 didn't give an error for me. It returned an IplConvKernel, as expected.

I'm assuming you're using an older version of OpenCV, since you're using the old naming convention for their functions (that is, cvCreateStructureElementEx vs CreateStructureElementEx). OpenCV has had a few errors here and there with the Python wrappers in the past - this might have been one of them.

Is it possible in your environment to update OpenCV to 2.3.x? And, if so, make sure you're also using either Python 2.6 or 2.7 - those are the only versions currently supported as far as I'm aware.

**Edit:** Hrm. Just saw the date on this one. Didn't realise I went back that far! Oh well, hopefuly useful to someone.